# How to run a background service in android to use accelerometer?

Tags: android, android-sensors, background-service

How to run a background service in android to use accelerometer?

I am already holding a listener to detect the accelerometer values. But i want to add this to a background service. So that even the app killed then i will get the values.

Please let me know the solution for this?

Any example is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

hi here is my source code check this out

```
 public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

int count = 1;
private boolean init;
private Sensor mySensor;
private SensorManager SM;
private float x1, x2, x3;
private static final float ERROR = (float) 7.0;
private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 15.00f; // m/S**2
private static final int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS = 1000;
private long mLastShakeTime;
private TextView counter;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) +
                    Math.pow(y, 2) +
                    Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            Log.d("mySensor", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

            if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALL DETECTED",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Start Detecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SM = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mySensor = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SM.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    //here u should make your service foreground so it will keep working even if app closed


    return Service.START_STICKY;

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain 

       if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALL DETECTED",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

Answer (score 0):

You are already using a listener to receive the accelerometer values. So, just create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which implements [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) and register this listener as you already have done.

But about keep the service running even after the app is killed, I think you should run your Service into another process, insert something like this into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <service android:name=".YourService"
        android:process=":accel_monitor>
 </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 9, only *foreground* services are allowed to do this according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview. This is probably because accelerometers can be used to determine how location has changed, and background location is a special opt-in permission.